# how to refer specific column of an entire list of dataframes in R function?

Tags: r

I have a multitude of dataframes in R that are like this & I know how to modify an entire column.

```
id    fire  earth   water 
1     5       7       9
2     23      34      54
3      1      2        3


df$fire <- (df$fire-5.5)/4.5
```

Im having a hard time finding the specific syntax to refer to **this specific column but of every df** (lets say fire)

```
df.list <- list(df1,df2,df3)

fire_function <- function(){(.$fire-5.5)/4.5}

lapply(df.list, fire_function)
```

Sorry if this question was already asked, i searched and couldn't find how to refer a specific column of all dataframes. Maybe my apply function is not appropriate either.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `transform`

```
df.list <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)
df.list <- lapply(df.list, transform, fire = (fire  - 5.5)/4.5)
```

If we need to update the original datasets, use `list2env`

```
list2env(df.list, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or we may need to assign and then return the data

```
df.list <- lapply(df.list, function(x) {
                x$fire <- (x$fire - 5.5)/4.5
                x})
```

Or create the `fire_function` as

```
fire_function <- function(x) {
                  x$fire <- (x$fire - 5.5)/4.5
                  x
     }
df.list <- lapply(df.list, fire_function)
```

Comment: transform worked for the df.list but how do i separate the df1, df2, df3 that were all group in a list ? because the modification is only in the listed object

Comment: @EmManuel if there are multiple datasets, it is preferable to keep it in list and do all the transformations instead of updating the original object. You could update original `names(df.list) <- c("df1", "df2", "df3");list2env(df.list, .GlobalEnv)`